# String longer than 2GB

Tags: vb.net, string, out-of-memory

I need to concatenate several text files together for which each input file is about 3.5GB.  These are simple files containing vbCrLf at the ends of lines.

Some previous code I used for fetching text streams from web pages (below) uses the Peek function (see below), and I wonder if Peek could somehow be used to read less than 2GB from a file --> write to the concatenated file, and then continue on the last half of each file?

```
 Dim encode As Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
 Dim readStream As New StreamReader(recvStream, encode)
 Dim sPage As String
 sPage = ""
 While (readStream.Peek() > -1)
   sPage += readStream.ReadLine() + vbCrLf
 End While
```

Basically, couldn't I read up to, say, 1.8GB using Peek, write(concatenate), Peek, concatenate etc. without losing anything after. Is there anything else that would take the 3.5GB Stream that I could work on to write with a StreamWriter?

Comment: Is the application a 64-bit application on a 64-bit version of Windows?

Comment: Have you seen the overload [StreamReader.Read Method (Char(), Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kstw824%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which allows you to read in chunks? Then, rather than storing the data in a string simply write it out to the destination file as you read each chunk. I suggest a buffer size of 32768 to start with.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew - StreamReader.Read worked and solved the problem.

Comment: @LEP If you found a solution, then please post it as an answer and accept it, so future readers might find it helpful

Comment: VB.net and VBA are different languages. The code and question are geared to VB.net but the title of the question and a tag are VBA. This is somewhat confusing. If it isn't VBA then it should be edited out.

Comment: A low-tech solution might work: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/keyboard-ninja/keyboard-ninja-concatenate-multiple-text-files-in-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Here was the solution:

```
 Dim encode As Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
 Dim readStream As New StreamReader(recvStream, encode)
 Dim str, sPage As String
 sPage = ""
 While (readStream.Peek() > -1)
   sPage += readStream.Read(str, 0, 32768) 
 End While
 'Next, split the string into lines at the carriage returns
 Dim Buff() As String = Split(sPage, vbCrLf)
```